# Bootstrap Navwalker 4 in Wordpress - How to add a depth 3 level

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I am using a WP_bootstrap_navwalker for a dropdown menu you can find it also here -> https://github.com/mebishalnapit/bootstrap-navwalker/.  It works , but it only shows me the first and second level items, the third level items appear  below all others instead of appearing in the right . So de dropdown on the first level and a regular second item when dropdown is open,. The third level is not visible. The bootstrap_navwalker code:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap NavWalker
 * Class Name: Bootstrap_NavWalker
 * Author: Bishal Napit
 * Author URI: https://napitwptech.com/
 * GitHub URI: https://github.com/mebishalnapit/bootstrap-navwalker/
 * Description: A custom WordPress nav walker class to implement the Bootstrap 4 navigation style in a custom WordPress
 * Bootstrap based theme using the WordPress built in menu manager.
 * License: GNU General Public License v3 or later
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */
class Bootstrap_NavWalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    // Create the $current_menu_id_bootstrap variable for generating the current menu id
    protected $current_menu_id_bootstrap;

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @see   Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        // Use the current menu id generated via start_el()
        $current_menu_id = $this->current_menu_id_bootstrap;

        // Assign the dynamic id for use inside the dropdown menu, ie, sub-menu for Bootstrap
        $id = 'aria-labelledby="navbar-dropdown-menu-link-' . $current_menu_id->ID . '"';

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }

        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        /**
         * Add the classes for the dropdown menu in WordPress
         *
         * 1. For WordPress default: '.sub-menu'
         * 2. For Bootstrap Sub-Menu: '.dropdown-menu'
         */
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu', 'dropdown-menu', 'common-bg' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Change <ul> to <div> for Bootstrap Navigation
         * Add the current menu id for the sub-menu toggle feature for Bootstrap
         */
        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<div $class_names $id>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @see   Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }

        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        /**
         * Change </ul> to </div> for Bootstrap Navigation
         */
        $output .= "$indent</div>{$n}";
    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     * @see   Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        // Find the current menu item id to be used for start_lvl()
        $this->current_menu_id_bootstrap = $item;

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : ( array ) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        /**
         * Add class '.nav-item' inside <li> tag for Bootstrap
         */
        $classes[] = 'nav-item';

        /**
         * Add class '.active' inside <li> tag for Bootstrap active menu as well as for the parent menu, which have the active sub-menu
         */
        if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) || in_array( 'current-menu-parent', $classes ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        }

        /**
         * Add class '.dropdown' inside <li> tag for Bootstrap dropdown menu, ie, <li> having sub-menu
         */
        if ( in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $classes ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'dropdown';
        }

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * <li> is required for parent menu only in Bootstrap
         */
        if ( $depth === 0 ) {
            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';
        }

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';

        /**
         * Add '.nav-link' class for <a> in parent menu for Bootstrap
         */
        if ( $depth === 0 ) {
            $atts['class'] = 'nav-link';
        }

        /**
         * Add the attributes for <a> in parent menu
         *
         * 1. Add '.dropdown-toggle' class for <a> in parent menu if it has sub-menu as required for Bootstrap
         * 2. Add '.dropdown' as 'data-toggle' attribute in <a> in parent menu if it has sub-menu as required for Bootstrap
         * 3. Add the current menu id attribute to indicate the exact menu to toggle for set in sub-menu div
         * 4. Add the attribute of 'true' for 'aria-haspopup' in parent menu to indicate it has sub-menus
         * 5. Add the attribute of 'false' for 'aria-expanded' in parent menu to indicate the sub-menus is hidden by default
         * 6. Add the '#' link in the <a> tag in the parent menu if it has sub-menu as required for Bootstrap
         */
        if (in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $classes ) ) {
            $atts['class']         .= ' dropdown-toggle';
            $atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
            $atts['id']            = 'navbar-dropdown-menu-link-' . $item->ID;
            $atts['aria-haspopup'] = "true";
            $atts['aria-expanded'] = "false";
            $atts['href']          = '#';
        }

        /**
         * Add the attributes for <a> in sub-menu
         * 1. Add '.dropdown-item' class for <a> inside sub-menu for Bootstrap
         * 2. Add the current menu id attribute if you want to style the menu differently
         */
        if ( $depth > 0 ) {
            $atts['class'] = 'dropdown-item';
            $atts['id']    = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        }

        /**
         * Add '.active' class inside <a> in sub-menu for Bootstrap
         */
        if ( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) ) {
            $atts['class'] .= ' active';
        }

        /**
         * Add '.disabled' class for <a> in menu for Bootstrap disabled class
         */
        if ( in_array( 'disabled', $item->classes ) ) {
            $atts['class'] .= ' disabled';
        }

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since                  3.6.0
         * @since                  4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array    $atts   {
         *                         The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         * @type string    $title  Title attribute.
         * @type string    $target Target attribute.
         * @type string    $rel    The rel attribute.
         * @type string    $href   The href attribute.
         *                         }
         *
         * @param WP_Post  $item   The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );

                /**
                 * If '.disabled' class is added to the menu, add the url of '#' in it
                 */
                if ( in_array( 'disabled', $item->classes ) ) {
                    $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( '#' ) : esc_attr( $value );
                }

                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @see   Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }

        /**
         * <li> is required for parent menu only in Bootstrap
         */
        if ( $depth === 0 ) {
            $output .= "</li>{$n}";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fallback menu
     * If you assign the fallback menu for your custom menu setup via wp_nav_menu function, then, this function will be
     * rendered if no menu is assigned to that menu location. You need to assign it via 'fallback_cb' array. Also, this
     * will be only rendered to the logged in users pointing them to the menu manager url.
     *
     * @param $args Arrays passed from the wp_nav_menu function
     */
    public static function fallback( $args ) {
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {
            $container       = $args['container'];
            $container_id    = $args['container_id'];
            $container_class = $args['container_class'];
            $menu_class      = $args['menu_class'];
            $menu_id         = $args['menu_id'];

            // If there is container render it
            if ( $container ) {
                echo '<' . esc_attr( $container );

                // If container id is set render it
                if ( $container_id ) {
                    echo ' id="' . esc_attr( $container_id ) . '"';
                }

                // If container class is set render it
                if ( $container_class ) {
                    echo ' class="' . esc_attr( $container_class ) . '"';
                }

                echo '>';
            }

            // Default wrapper for menu is <ul>
            echo '<ul';

            // If menu id has been set render it
            if ( $menu_id ) {
                echo ' id="' . esc_attr( $menu_id ) . '"';
            }

            // If menu class has been set render it
            if ( $menu_class ) {
                echo ' class="' . esc_attr( $menu_class ) . '"';
            }

            // Close <ul> div wrapper for menu
            echo '>';

            // Display the link to Add New Menu
            echo '<li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="' . esc_url( admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) ) . '">';
            esc_html_e( 'Add a menu', 'theme-textdomain' );
            echo '</a></li>';

            // Close the main <ul>
            echo '</ul>';

            // Close the main container div
            if ( $container ) {
                echo '</' . esc_attr( $container ) . '>';
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my header.php file where i added depth 3 to the bootstrapnavwalker:

```
<div class="navigation-wrap common-bg full">
        <div class="container-xl p-0">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 p-0">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_home_url()?>">
                                <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="<?php echo $GLOBALS['txt']['logo_alt'];?>" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" width="200" height="55"/>
                            </a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">

                        <button class="navbar-toggler mx-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-menu">
                            <?php
                            wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'menu'              => 'Top',
                                'theme_location'    => 'Top',
                                'depth'             => 3,
                                'container'         => false,
                                'menu_class'        => 'navbar-nav ml-auto py-4 py-md-0',
                                'fallback_cb'       => 'Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                                'walker'            => new Bootstrap_Navwalker()
                                ));
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </nav>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if(!is_search() && !is_archive() && !is_404()):?>
        <h1 class="page-heading text-center title-accent py-4 mb-0"><?php the_title();?></h1>
        <?php elseif(is_archive()):?>
        <h1 class="page-heading text-center title-accent py-4 mb-0"><?php the_archive_title();?></h1>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>
```

I tried adding depth 3 i also tried fiddling a bit with the navwalker but for some reason whenever i try to change something the whole navigation gets jumbled up and breaks.

Comment: _"the third level items appear below all others instead of appearing in the right . So de dropdown on the first level and a regular second item when dropdown is open,. The third level is not visible."_ - I'd start by checking whether this is a problem with the HTML output, or the CSS formatting applied to it.